# Showing the count of tokens as 1 for any String

Tags: java, string

I tried to use the countTokens() method in java,it is showing only 1 as no of tokens for any input that i give as a string.

```
import java.util.*;

public class uhu {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("Hit n");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    try {
        int n = sc.nextInt();//scan the size of the array
        String[] str=new String[n];
        System.out.println("Enter elements");
        sc.nextLine();
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) //scanning the elements 
        {
            str[i]=sc.nextLine();
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) //printing the count of tokens
        {
            StringTokenizer st=new StringTokenizer(str[i]);
            System.out.println("Count of tokens for "+i+"string is :"+st.countTokens());
        }
    } finally {
        if (sc != null)
            sc.close();
    }

  }

}
```

Comment: 41 minutes ago, you posted another question and were asked to be specific, and to provide the input, expected output, and actual output. Do the same for this question, and for all the future questions you'll ask.

Answer (score 0):

Use of StringTokenizer is discouraged nowadays. Use String.split() instead

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)

Since by default StringTokenizer splits the string using space, use split(" ") which will break the string using space

Comment: That doesn't answer the question. Just because it's discouraged doesn't mean it can't be used and has a bug.

Answer (score 0):

By default `StringTokenizer` uses a delimiter list of a space character, tab character,  newline character, carriage-return character, and form-feed character.

Chances are that your input `String` does not contain any of these characters resulting in a token count of `1`.

Try delimiting your input `String` with spaces.